# Sum over partition by- Power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to achieve this using dax.

[image: Query image]

I have a table with date, month, year and amount.

I want to create a measure which gives me the desired output in power bi.
This desired output only changes every time there is a change in the date, month and year.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following measure :

```
DesiredOutput = CALCULATE(
             SUM('yourTable'[Amount]),
             FILTER(ALL('yourTable'),
             'yourTable'[Month]=MAX('yourTable'[Month])))
```